# Google maps api - Streetview, geocoding and pov heading

Tags: javascript, maps, geocoding, google-street-view, heading

I'm trying to show a streetview of a property and angle the streetview camera towards that property.

The latlng of the property is geocoded using the address and google's geocoding service.

Using the latlng of the property and the latlng of the streetview, a heading is calculated using computeHeading but the camera still isn't angled towards the property.

The problem seems to be that the latlng of the property returned by google's geocoding service is in the middle of the street and not on top of the actual property. The latlng of the streetview position is also in the middle of the street. Therefor, the heading calculated doesn't angle the camera towards the property but towards a point in the street.

Is there a way to get around this problem? Any geocoding service that will geocode an address to the actual building and not the closest point on the street? Any other solution to get better results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't seem to offer rooftop geocoding in Canada.